# I'm getting 'module' object is not callable in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, django-rest-viewsets

I'm trying to learn django rest framework for an api. I'm following the documentation and checked all the imports but I'm getting the typeerror: 'module' object is not callable

**Views.py**

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .serializer import CategorySerializer
from .models import CategoryModel

class FirstView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = CategoryModel.objects.all().order_by('name')
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import CategoryModel

class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CategoryModel
        field = ['name', 'description']
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path, include

from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from . import views

router = DefaultRouter()

router.register(r'', views.FirstView)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls))
]
```

**Error**

```
Internal Server Error: /api/category/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\aashu\.virtualenvs\lcodev-xFWoZVV6\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\aashu\.virtualenvs\lcodev-xFWoZVV6\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\aashu\.virtualenvs\lcodev-xFWoZVV6\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\aashu\.virtualenvs\lcodev-xFWoZVV6\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\aashu\.virtualenvs\lcodev-xFWoZVV6\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\viewsets.py", line 125, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\aashu\.virtualenvs\lcodev-xFWoZVV6\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 492, in dispatch
    request = self.initialize_request(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\aashu\.virtualenvs\lcodev-xFWoZVV6\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\viewsets.py", line 146, in initialize_request
    request = super().initialize_request(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\aashu\.virtualenvs\lcodev-xFWoZVV6\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 394, in initialize_request
    authenticators=self.get_authenticators(),
  File "C:\Users\aashu\.virtualenvs\lcodev-xFWoZVV6\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 272, in get_authenticators
    return [auth() for auth in self.authentication_classes]
  File "C:\Users\aashu\.virtualenvs\lcodev-xFWoZVV6\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 272, in <listcomp>
    return [auth() for auth in self.authentication_classes]
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

This is the settings.py which is for DjangoRestFramework

**settings.py**

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
     'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authtoken',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly'
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please show the complete error.

Comment: @isAif I attached the full error. Please help me :-)

Comment: Show what authenticators you have configured in settings. Something’s pointing to a module instead of a class there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your settings are misconfigured. [The manual says](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication):

> ### TokenAuthentication
>
> ..
>
> To use the `TokenAuthentication` scheme you'll need to configure the authentication classes to include `TokenAuthentication`, and additionally include `rest_framework.authtoken` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting:
>
> ```
> INSTALLED_APPS = [
>     ...
>     'rest_framework.authtoken'
> ]
> ```

The `rest_framework.authtoken` is to be put into ***`INSTALLED_APPS`***, not `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES`. I'm not entirely sure what the documentation insinuates is to be put into `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES` though; most likely:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        ...,
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication'
    ],
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Finally It worked! Thank youu sooo muchh :)